# Unable to select value of dropdown using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am trying to set value in "select" control using jQuery. It is observed that sometime it select value correctly and sometime it does not select value.

I have an xml document, below code pull xml value and set it to dropdown list (html select)
This is my jQuery Bock.

```
var select = '#' + formname + ' select[binding="true"]'; //here select those dropdown whose binding property is true.
$(select).each(function (i) {
    var bindName = $(this).attr("DataMember");
    if (bindName != '') {
        $xmlNode = $xml.find(bindName);
        if ($xmlNode != null) {
            var value = $xmlNode.text();
            if (value == "0")
                value = '';
            $(this).val(value); //here actual value is set as per xml value
        }
        else
            $(this).val('');
        $(this).trigger("change");
        $(this).trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
});
```

Some time this code works some time it does not work.
can anybody let me know what's the problem with this code.

Comment: Hi Manish, this is one that may be impossible to guess at without an example, which is likely why there are no answers yet. Would you consider replicating the issue on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Well, It would be difficult to replicate this issue on jsfiddle.net as there are lot of thing, this is SPA. and code is mention is just a part. when the document is ready, i am assuming that all the html control is render and available for manipulation by jQuery. I also observed that this occurs only for the first time after that it works fine.

Comment: Okay, understood. Hopefully, someone will have some inspiration that will help you get to the answer.